# Cloud function to get download links for images in storage bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Hey folks I have an existing API layer using google cloud functions, and I was looking a way to get the download url for an image in Cloud Storage using a specific api endpoint.

```
app.get('/api/images/:ref', async (req, res) => {
    const { ref } = req.params
    try {
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('bucket name')
        const path = ref
        const img = await bucket.file(path).download()
        return img
    } catch (error) { return res.status(500).json(error.mesasge) }
}
)
```

and my refernce path for an image is like foldername/randomID

Will this be possible through an api endpoint through passing params.

Comment: I edited the question to remove references to Firestore because you're not using that product here at all.  If you meant Firebase, that is a different thing.  What you are looking for is called a "signed URL" in Cloud Storage terms.

Comment: Signed Url got it thanks for the clarification